# Qt. Проблемы с QVector<MyClass>

Tags: c++, qt

Есть класс такого рода:

```
#ifndef SOME_H
#define SOME_H

#include <QPoint>
#include <QColor>

class Some
{
public:
    QPoint point;
    QColor color;    
public:
    Some(QColor c, QPoint p) : color(c), point(p) { }
};

#endif // SOME_H
```

При создании вектора и добавлении объектов этого класса - выдает ошибку.

```
QVector<Some> s;
s.push_back(Some(QColor(Qt::red), QPoint(0, 0)));
```

Ошибка:

> no matching function for call to ‘Some::Some()’
>                new (from++) T();
>                ^

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [документации](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html#assignable-data-type) сказано, что:

> The values stored in the various containers can be of any assignable
>   data type. To qualify, a type **must provide a default constructor**, a
>   copy constructor, and an assignment operator.

В вашем классе нет конструктора по умолчанию, соответственно его нельзя использовать в Qt-контейнерах. Можно добавить аргументы по умолчанию в текущий конструктор, это тоже решит проблему:

```
Some(QColor c = QColor(Qt::red), QPoint p = QPoint(0, 0)) : color(c), point(p) { }
```